# Gamma Distribution in R (qgamma)

Tags: r, quantile, gamma

This may be a very stupid question but
Does anyone know why i am not getting the second bit equals to the mean (100)?

```
#beta=4, alpha=5, mean=20
qgamma(0.5, 5, 1/4)
# 18.68364

#beta=2500, alpha=0.04, mean=100
qgamma(0.5,0.04,1/2500)
# 0.00004320412
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using the quantile function, and `qgamma(0.5, shape, scale)` corresponds to the median - not the mean as you are expecting.

See the example below;

```
x <- rgamma(50000, shape = 0.04, scale = 2500)
mean(x)
# [1] 98.82911

median(x)
# [1] 3.700012e-05
```

Comment: Do you know how can i use the gamma distribution with the same parameter (alpha=0.04, beta=2500) to 
- generate a 10k sims
- duplicate the sims n times (randomly reorder each simulation without repeating)
?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: @yang you can use this `matrix(rgamma(n * k, shape = 0.04, scale = 2500), nrow = k, ncol = n)`. Since one draw from the `rgamma` is independent from the other, you can simply generate all at once and then put them in a matrix.